# Was Ramakrishna Paramhansa an avatar of Vishnu?

Tags: avatars, vivekananda, ramakrishna

I have heard Swami Vivekananda quoting that Ramakrishna was verily an avatar. I was initially agnostic about it, but now I am totally convinced. If possible please add Shastric references for avatar criteria etc.

Comment: I know, thats why I asked for Shastra references.

Comment: You are still asking for opinion. Remove that statement.

Comment: According to his biography he was an avatara of Vishnu.. Lord Vishnu came in his father's dream, while he was in a Gaya Vishnu temple, that he will be born as his son.. @ArkaprabhaMajumdar

Comment: Alright I didn't see that question @Rickross ...... Although he has asked specifically for shastras.

Comment: Should I vote to close a close friend's question? :P

Comment: Btw for all this useless banter, I mentioned shastras in the context of Avatar criteria etc. I never asked for predictions of Ramakrishna or its validation. I know a lot of shastras have Avatar criteria mentioned in them.

Comment: This question is not an "EXACT" duplicate like you guys have marked. That question is specifically asking "WHERE IS IT WRITTEN", while mine is not about where that might be written. I only just asked for Shastric references for avatar criteria.